# what kind of username should be given in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

i am trying install sql server 2005 from last hour but i can't create username and password and domain in sql server 2005.
But i am became mad bcz sql server is not accepting username and password of mine.
i tried a lots of ones.
i am only making simple application which is only for test purpose only.
so any one can gave me any name & password or any link in which they have given any valid username and password of sql server 2005.

EDIT: i am trying to give Mixed Mode authentication in sql server 2005. 
i had tried to follow this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.1399.06&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=SQLSetup90&EvtType=28075) but then also i can't make it.

Comment: Correct: you "can't create domain username and password and domain in sql server 2005."  It has to be an existing domain user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HOSTNAME\username

Should be the username that has permissions for MSSQL.